# Follow-up 2: Copy File, remove spaces in specific lines

Tags: java, object-oriented, file

This is an iterative review: [The Original Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163557/copy-file-remove-spaces-in-specific-lines) | [Follow up 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163761/follow-up-1-copy-file-remove-spaces-in-specific-lines)

**Differences to Follow up 1**

This iteration tries to take the previous review to heart and see how it turns out. It sacrifices the flexibility to easily exchange sourceReader/sinkWriter classes that may read/write from different sources/sinks and specify that they read/write as BufferedReader/PrintWriter from/to files specified in the arguments in order to make the program less bulky. I'm unsure how to evaluate this change because I see reasons pro flexibility/bulky program as well as contra flexibility/bulky program. For the magnitude of this program and its actual task, I guess it might have been overkill.

---

Here the relevant sections of the previous questions:

> The task itself is to go through a large .txt file that contains lines with ">" as their first character and to remove all spaces in
>   these lines. I am using this program to modify files in FASTA format,
>   a format often used in biology.
>
> **Algorithm**
>
> 1. Read next line from input file and store in "line"
> 2. If "line" contains ">" as first character, remove all spaces in "line"
> 3. Print "line" to output file
> 4. If next line is not null, go back to Step 1

**Changes to Argument Handling**

In the process I also updated the argument handling process with my custom-written classes. Argument handling is still done by an ArgumentHandler, custom for every program, and an `ArgumentCollectionImplementation` class that implements the interface `ArgumentCollection`.

The `ArgumentCollectionImplementation` contains a List of all flags possible for this program upon instantiation (including a default String to print if -h is called) and gets the arguments of these flags added to it during argument parsing. It contains methods to receive and change one or all arguments of a given flag as well as methods to add and test arguments for int/double.

Setting default values of arguments, throwing errors if mandatory flags don't have an argument and similar tasks are all handled by the ArgumentHandler, implementing interface `Configuration` (of which I see very little use outside of this program) that provides the necessary methods `getSinkFile()`and `getSourceFile()` for the Client. Since the ArgumentHandler is program specific, it makes only sense to include it as private static class of the Client `RemoveSpacesClient`.

---

**Client - including ArgumentHandler**

```
public class RemoveSpacesClient {
    private static class RemoveSpacesArgumentHandler implements Configuration {
        private ArgumentCollection arguments;

        RemoveSpacesArgumentHandler(String[] args) {
            /*- Define all allowed Flags in the ArgumentCollection and add text for help flag:
             * -i: input flag
             * -o: output flag
             * -h: help flag*/
            String[] argumentList = { "-i", "-o", "-h", "Text to display if -h is called" };
            arguments = new ArgumentCollectionImplementation1(argumentList);

            /*- Parse arguments and add them to their associated flags in the ArgumentCollection*/
            arguments.parseArguments(args);

            /* Test mandatory flag -i for arguments */
            if (!arguments.flagHasArguments("-i")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Mandatory flag -i was not specified");
            }

            /* Add a default argument to flag "-o" if it has no argument */
            if (!arguments.flagHasArguments("-o")) {
                arguments.addFlagArgument("-o", 0, arguments.getFlagStringArgument("-i") + ".nospace.txt");
            }
        }

        public File getSourceFile() {
            return new File(arguments.getFlagStringArgument("-i"));
        }

        public File getSinkFile() {
            return new File(arguments.getFlagStringArgument("-o"));
        }

        public void printArguments() {
            arguments.printArguments();
        }
    }

    private static void printProgramProgress(int i) {
        if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i / 1000000 + " * 10^6 lines written.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration arguments = new RemoveSpacesArgumentHandler(args);

        System.out.println("Starting Program with the following arguments: ");
        arguments.printArguments();

        BufferedReader sourceReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arguments.getSourceFile()));
        PrintWriter sinkWriter = new PrintWriter(arguments.getSinkFile());

        /*
         * Write every line from source-file to sink-file. If the line is a
         * sequence name (first character is ">"), remove all spaces in it
         * before writing.
         */
        int i = 0;
        for (String line = sourceReader.readLine(); line != null; line = sourceReader.readLine()) {
            if (line.charAt(0) == '>') {
                line = line.replace(" ", "");
            }
            sinkWriter.println(line);
            printProgramProgress(++i);
        }
        sourceReader.close();
        sinkWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }
}
```

In a seperate class "CustomInterfaces" I have also Configuration

```
public interface Configuration {
    /**
     * Returns the name and path of a file to read from in form of a String.
     */
    File getSourceFile();

    /**
     * Returns the name and path of a file to write to in form of a String.
     */
    File getSinkFile();

    /** Prints all arguments */
    void printArguments();
}
```

---

**Requests**

1. Am I correct in my assessment that a Configuration interface here is somewhat unnecessary, seeing as I *think* I would hardly be able to reuse the interface.
2. The Client code throws 4 places where Exceptions can occur:

   1. When `sourceReader` is instantiated (`FileNotFoundException`),
   2. when `sinkWriter` is instantiated (`FileNotFoundException`),
   3. when `sourceReader` reads a line from source (`IOException`),
   4. when `sourceReader` is closed (`IOException`).

I came to the conclusion that there is not a lot the Client can do in case any of these occur, baring terminal-User-interaction that force the user to re-enter incorrect arguments until the input no longer causes exceptions. As such I let main throw an IOException. Was that wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the following code :

```
    BufferedReader sourceReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arguments.getSourceFile()));
    PrintWriter sinkWriter = new PrintWriter(arguments.getSinkFile());

    /*
     * Write every line from source-file to sink-file. If the line is a
     * sequence name (first character is ">"), remove all spaces in it
     * before writing.
     */
    int i = 0;
    for (String line = sourceReader.readLine(); line != null; line = sourceReader.readLine()) {
        if (line.charAt(0) == '>') {
            line = line.replace(" ", "");
        }
        sinkWriter.println(line);
        printProgramProgress(++i);
    }
    sourceReader.close();
    sinkWriter.close();
    System.out.println("Finished!");
```

if an exception occurs at any point, files may not be properly closed.

I won't show the java 6 idiom for managing this case (because it's ugly and if you are still using java 6 you really should upgrade your version) but if you are using java 7, you should use `try-with-ressources` to avoid all the unnecessary closes.

This is how it looks like :

```
try (BufferedReader sourceReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yolo"))) {
    // do some stuff here
} // no need to close sourceReader
```

If you are using java 8+, you should take a look the new static methods in the `Files` class (*nio* package) and how to manipulate `Stream` objects.

About your `Configuration` interface, yeah... it's better removed, because it is so coupled to the rest of your code you will probably never have another implementation besides `RemoveSpacesArgumentHandler`.